# Why doesn't my scoreboard update in pygame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I'm making a scoreboard for my tennis game. Why doesn't it update when the ball stops?

I've tried shuffling the indentation around, removing the for loop.

```py
while carryOn:
    font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 32)
    screen.fill(OUT)

    camden.update()
    robert.update()
    tennisball.update()

    epsilonComp = .1
    stops = []
    ballstop = abs(tennisball.speedx) < epsilonComp and abs(tennisball.speedy) < epsilonComp
    if abs(tennisball.speedx) < epsilonComp and abs(tennisball.speedy) < epsilonComp:
        stops.append(1)
        if sum(stops) == 2:
            score = 15
        elif sum(stops) == 3:
            score = 30
    scorebox = font.render(str(score), True, WHITE, BLACK)
    scoreRect = scorebox.get_rect()
    scoreRect.center = (625, 50)
    screen.blit(scorebox, scoreRect)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            carryOn = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_x:
                carryOn = False



    all_sprites.update()

    # Update
    all_sprites.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
```

It should update to 15 when the ball stops, and then 30 when it stops again. If someone can fix this I can fix the rest of the score.

Comment: The score shows up, it just stays at 0 when the ball stops

Comment: Are you sure the "ballstop" condition is ever met?  Maybe print out the values as it processes.

Answer (score 1):

The condition `if sum(stops) == 2:` is never fulfilled, because `stops` is initialized in every frame. `sum(stops)` will never be more than 1. Do `stops = []` before the main loop:

```py
stops = []
while carryOn:

    # [...]

    #stops = [] <---- DELETE this
    ballstop = abs(tennisball.speedx) < epsilonComp and abs(tennisball.speedy) < epsilonComp
    if abs(tennisball.speedx) < epsilonComp and abs(tennisball.speedy) < epsilonComp:
        stops.append(1)
        if sum(stops) == 2:
            score = 15
        elif sum(stops) == 3:
            score = 30
```

Possibly the condition `if sum(stops) == 2:` is wrong and it has to be `if sum(stops) == 1:`. But that depends on your game logic. If the ball is in "stopped" at the beginning, then `if sum(stops) == 2:` will be correct.

---

According to the comments:

When the ball has stopped then you've to set a state `ball_is_stopped = True`. In the condition, which evaluates the if the ball has stopped you've to evaluate this state, so that stopping of the ball, doesn't cause a running score:

```py
if not ball_is_stopped and ....
    ball_is_stopped = True
```

When the ball starts to move, then you've to reset the state, so that the next stop can increment the score. Init the state by `True`, because at the beginning the ball is stopped, but the score should not be incremented.

```py
if abs(tennisball.speedx) > epsilonComp and abs(tennisball.speedy) > epsilonComp:
    ball_is_stopped = False
```

Further it is not necessary, that `stops` is a list, a counter is completely sufficient. Increment the counter as long `count` is less than 3.

```py
stops = stops+1
if stops == 4: 
    stops = 0
```

The full code which increments the score may look like this:

```py
scores = [0, 15, 30, 40]
stops = 0
games = 0
ball_is_stopped = True

while carryOn:

    # [...]

    epsilonComp = .1
    is_moving = abs(tennisball.speedx) > epsilonComp or abs(tennisball.speedy) > epsilonComp
    if is_moving:
        ball_is_stopped = False

    if not ball_is_stopped and not is_moving:
        ball_is_stopped = True

        stops = stops+1
        if stops == 4:
            stops = 0
            games += 1

        score = scores[stops]
```

Comment: Sums stops 2 is correct as you said. Since this post I have moved the list outside the loop but will try your solution when I am home. Thanks

Comment: https://pastebin.com/XEHsEq3n @Rabbid76 now the scoreboard doesn't update. I got this far on my own but this scoreboard is really stumping me :/

Comment: Of course it doesn't update, because the condition `elif sum(stops) == 2:` is never reached. Since `ball_is_stopped = True`, `if ball_is_stopped:` is always fulfilled and `elif sum(stops) == 2:` is never evaluated. Just change `elif` to `if`: `if sum(stops) == 2:`

Comment: Will try that again when I get back. Thanks regardless for the help so far

Comment: changed that, now it just runs through to 0 like a clock. Then it stops.

Comment: not sure if my last comment tagged you so here you go

Comment: @RobertSmith Sorry I didn't get a notification. You've to add "@<name>" to notify a user. But I've extended the answer.